# mongo aggregation speed

Tags: mongodb

I'm a new user of mongo (with extensive experience with mysql) and it seems to have some interesting pros and cons.  The pros are, apparently, the size of the data you can hold and the speed at which you can write records.  I have an application where I'm writing many logs to a collection and I have about 7m so far.  My problem is that a seemingly simple query takes a really **REALLY** long time.  Let me explain.

My collection has 7m documents:

```
> db.alpha2.count()
7257619
```

Now I want to count all records for a given cid and that has a timestamp less than some number (this example has the timestamp in the future, so it should count everything):

```
> db.alpha2.find({'ts': {'$lt': 1446457607}, 'cid': '2636518'}).count()
7257619
```

This is the problem query, it takes a full **58 seconds** to return this number to me!  Conceptually, this is a very simple query and would be somewhat equivalent to this in sql world:

```
select count(*) from alpha2 where cid=2636518 and ts<1446457607
```

I don't have an equivalent table, but I think that would take less than 0.1 seconds to run in mysql based on my experience.  So what do I do?  I plan on doing a lot of aggregation counting on datasets much bigger than 7m records.  I'm also doing some slightly harder stuff (map reduce) and that's much much worse (a few minutes).  I need this to be less than a second.  What am I doing wrong?  Is this time cost expected with mongo?

I put an index on the ts value with this prior to my timing on the queries above:

```
db.alpha2.ensureIndex({ts:1})
```

Comment: With only an index on ts column the SQL would also probably take a long time if the number of records matched by ts<1446457607 is huge.  You need a compound index on cid and ts to make this faster.

Answer (score 4):

In order to determine the `count()`, MongoDB will have to find all matching documents.

You can [explain()](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Explain) the query to see how the indexes are used:

```
 db.alpha2.find({'ts': {'$lt': 1446457607}, 'cid': '2636518'}).explain()
```

In particular you want to minimize the `nscannedObjects` (number of documents scanned).

Your best case standard scenario is to index on all fields involved in the count (and ensure the index fits in available RAM).

So, your index should include `cid` as well:

```
 db.alpha2.ensureIndex({ts:1, cid:1})
```

If you are doing frequent counts, you may be better storing and updating these via a process like an [incremental map/reduce](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce#MapReduce-MongoShellScriptwithIncrementalMapReduceandFinalize) if that works for your use case.

Comment: There are also some open suggestions in MongoDB's issue tracker for improving count performance for various use cases (all docs in a collection, per attribute, finding distinct values, ...).  For example: [SERVER-1752](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1752) (improve the performance of count({attr:val})).

Comment: Note that SERVER-1752 has been addressed in the 2.3.2 development release, so the performance of counts will be significantly improved in the MongoDB 2.4 production release for some common use cases.